# Is this a list or string in Python?

Tags: python, email, imap

Based on [this](http://yuji.wordpress.com/2011/06/22/python-imaplib-imap-example-with-gmail/) I am experimenting with imap and gmail using python .

using the python REPL, I have:

```
>>> m.select('[Gmail]/Sent Mail')
('OK', ['35'])
>>> result, data = m.uid('search', None, "ALL")
>>> data
['1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35']
```

First I gather this is a list object not a string, because when I run

```
>>> print data.split(' ')
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

why are there no commas? and why does the following appear to work

```
>>> print data[0].split(' ')
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35']
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This demonstration should answer your question:

```
>>> data = ['1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35']
>>> type(data) # It is a list
<type 'list'>
>>> len(data)  # It has one item
1
>>> type(data[0]) # That item is a string
<type 'str'>
>>> data[0] 
'1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35'
>>> data[0].split(' ') # Like all strings, it has a `split` method
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15','16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31','32', '33','34', '35']
>>>
```

So, `data` is a list with one item that is a string.  Moreover, writing `data[0].split(' ')` calls the `split` method of that string and has it split on spaces.

Answer (score 4):

It is a single string within a list

```
>>> type(['1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35'])
<type 'list'>
>>> [type('1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35')]
[<type 'str'>]
```

The following works because `str.split(' ')` splits every white-space character and `data[0]` means the first element within `data` which is the string:

```
>>> print data[0].split(' ') #You've selected the string out of the list
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35']
```